# javascript socket.on(..) is not being called

Tags: javascript, socket.io

So I have a simple website that I am working on, for socket communication and chat ability demonstration, where the server is written in python flask app, and the client uses javascript. here is a snippet of code from the server:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on("message")
def chat(data):
    mfrom = data["username"]
    channel = data["channel"]
    message = data["message"]
    #print(f"a meesage received from {mfrom}")
    emit("msg_cast", {"username": mfrom, "channel": channel, "message": message}, broadcast=True)
```

as you can see, the server gets a message event and emits a msg_cast event.

where as the client successfully connects:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
...
...
  var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
...
```

...
later on it has :

```
socket.on('msg_cast', data => {

        alert('message was received ');
        let id = localStorage('ids_counter');
        // Create new div content.
        const cont1 = document.createElement('div');
        cont1.className = 'list-group-item list-group-item-action active text-white rounded-0';
        cont1.id = "chat_elem" + id.toString();
        document.querySelector('#list_recent_msgs').appendChild(cont1);
        var id_str = cont1.id;

        id +=1;

        const cont2 = document.createElement('div');
        cont2.className = 'media-body ml-4';
        cont2.id = "chat_elem" + id.toString();
        document.querySelector(id_str).appendChild(cont2);
        var id_str2 = cont2.id;
        id += 1;

        const cont3 = document.createElement('div');
        cont3.className = 'd-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-1'
        cont3.id = "chat_elem" + id.toString();
        document.querySelector(id_str2).appendChild(cont3);
        id_str = cont3.id;
        id += 1;

        // added h6 of the sender name
        const cont4 = document.createElement('h6');
        cont4.className = 'mb-0';
        cont4.innerHTML = data.username;
        cont4.id = "chat_elem" + id.toString();
        document.querySelector(id_str).appendChild(cont4);
        id_str = cont3.id;

        // added paragraph of the msg content
        const cont5 = document.createElement('p');
        cont5.className = 'font-italic mb-0 text-small';
        cont5.innerHTML = data.message;
        document.querySelector(id_str2).appendChild(cont5);

        localStorage.setItem('ids_counter', id)
        alert(' done all the job');
       });
```

but then the first alert('message was received ');`
 is never called, though I know that the server does indeed send the msg_cast message, it never is handled by the client, and I know that if I remove this code form the client everything works fine, except sometimes trouble comes from a different place than expected, and the console shows no issues whatsoever.

Also, there is a form that should be filled in order for the code to start running, and when I submit the form the page jumps to the start as if it is a sign of some javascript code that is not right. 
can you help? see what's wrong and why is the socket.on(msg_cast .. is not called?

thanks.

Comment: How did you import the socket.io from the client?

Comment: javascript is the client side here. inside the index.html I have the following: <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>

Comment: I also send to the server once a form is filled like this :   document.querySelector('#chat_msgs_form').onsubmit = () => {

    const username = document.getElementById("username_head").innerHTML;
    const channel = document.getElementById('chat_msg_head').innerHTML;
    const message = document.querySelector('#chat_msg_body').value;

    socket.on('connect', () => {
        socket.emit('message', {'username': username, "channel": channel, "message": message});
     });

Comment: Did you make sure your server socketio version is exactly the same as the front's?

Comment: server socketIO version is 4.2.1, while for client I used 1.3.6 as shown in the comment above, I also used 2.2.0 still both versions should work just fine with this server flask default version. and there;s no client version of 4.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Found the 3 problems:

1. Instead of let id = `localStorage('ids_counter');`
   I should have let id = `localStorage.getItem('ids_counter');`
2. This line `document.querySelector(id_str).appendChild(cont2);` is failing on 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null'

It was because of not using getElementById instead when I am using variable id.

The third and most important is this code:

```
  document.querySelector('#chat_msgs_form').onsubmit = () => {

        var elem = document.getElementById("username_head");
        const username = elem.innerHTML;
        elem = document.getElementById('chat_msg_head');
        const channel = elem.innerHTML;
        elem = document.querySelector('#chat_msg_body');
        const message = elem.value;

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            socket.emit('message', {'username': username, "channel": channel, "message": message});
         });
        //alert(' after connect');
        socket.on('msg_cast', data => {
```

...

Because I am inside `.onsubmit` handling of an event, I should simply do `socket.emit` instead of wrapping around with `socket.on ('connect')`. Once I remove this the `socket.on` is called.